# Removing \CheckSum and \CharacterTable for some generated files

Tags: dtx, docstrip

How can you prevent `\CheckSum` and `\CharacterTable` appearing in some of the generated files (examples include README, ChangeLog, LaTeX example files, ...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use

```
\generate{\nopreamble\nopostamble ....
```

To stop docstrip adding anything to the file but the character table and `\CheckSum` is not generated text it is just copied from the source dtx file as literal `%%` comments. So if you don't put it in the source it won't be in the result. Or if you want it in some files but not others, use docstrip guards such as

```
%<*package>
```

so it only appears in the package `.sty` file and not in other files.

Unless you are in the habit of sending files through BITNET/JANET/internet gateways that tended to scramble tex markup, I wouldn't bother adding these tables now.

Comment: Thanks David. Suppose you generate 100 `.sty` files from a single `.dtx` source, then is it possible to insert `\CheckSum` and `\CharacterTable` automatically after each `<*packag.sty>`?

Comment: @VafaKhalighi yes it all depends how you set up the guards, if the character table is guarded by `<*table>` ... `</table>` then you just need to make sure that the ins file specifies `table`  when generating each .sty file

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. After all, it was not as hard as I thought it was.